# Uniform grid with gridlines always visible (WPF)

Tags: wpf, uniformgrid

I would need to create a WPF component that accepts a row and column layout ​​as input
(2 rows and 2 columns, 3 rows and 3 columns, etc.).

So I took a listview and as itempaneltemplate I use a uniformgrid.

When I add an element to the listview (which is a usercontrol, added via a datatemplate) it is set according to the uniform grid layout.

What I can't implement is that when I set up a layout, I would like the boxes that will then be filled by my user control at runtime to be visible even when the listview is empty.

Sample Image:
[image]

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean with "visible". If you set both Columns and Rows of the UniformGrid, you should get an C x R grid even if the children count is less than C*R.

Comment: With visible i mean that i my layout it's 3 x 3 e.g. I want to see 9 box with border for example even if my listview haave only one element

Comment: Which border? You do see a 3x3 layout if you set both properties.

Comment: I've added a picture in the post of what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Uniformgrid is just a panel.
She has no means of marking boundaries.
In each cell, you need to place a Border with its own borders.
And in the Content Border (where necessary) place the output of the required element.

One example: [Draw samurai sudoku grid on WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67941969/draw-samurai-sudoku-grid-on-wpf/67943072#67943072)