# Draw samurai sudoku grid on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, desktop, sudoku

I want to draw a samurai sudoku grid on my C# WPF project.
this is the example of samurai sudoku

[image: https://www.samurai-sudoku.com/sudoku3.gif]

for each TextBox within the grid, I want to load it with dynamic value from the txt file.

txt file : "23987239847239847" (in total 405 integers)

I already have the normal sudoku grid working

code:

```
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding Dimension}" Columns="{Binding Dimension}" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

What are the most efficient ways to draw a grid that looks like a samurai suoku grid?

Comment: "Is there a way to draw the grid?"   Perhaps you need to rephrase that question because, if you are to be taken literally, then the answer is **yes, there is a way**.  What do you actually need to know?  What did you try?

Comment: One of the possible options.
Make UniformGrid 21x21.
In the cells set Border with the required background and borders.
Put TextBox inside Border.
And it's better to use not a TextBox, but a ComboBox with a list of valid values.

Comment: @EldHasp, Why 21x21? because you have 81x5(405) Textboxes/Comboxes right?

Comment: UniformGrid automatically splits the entire field into equal sized columns and rows.
Child elements are automatically placed sequentially in all cells.
For the Grid, you have to specify a collection of rows and columns.
And for each daughter element, set the coordinate in which cell to place it.

Comment: For this, the total number of cells in height and width is 21.
How much, then, to split?
In empty cells (between Sudoku blocks) set the output of transparent Border.

Comment: You are using ItemsControl.
In those places where there should be empty space, write null.

Comment: @EldHasp for the empty cells, should I make a validator to skip it and not bind it to a value? another question: does xaml also work with conditions for specific cells to skip?

Comment: If you do not need to set borders of different thickness, then of course a regular TextBox will be enough for a cell.

Comment: " for the empty cells, should I make a validator to skip it and not bind it to a value?" - Set a style trigger that compares the current context to null.
Add a setter to the trigger with Opacity = 0.

Comment: @EldHasp the UniformGrid Rows and Colums should be both 21? and Datatemplate I need to add border and inside a border a textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example for demonstration.
It is not as difficult as in the picture in the question.
But it will not be a problem for you to supplement it.

```
public class SudokuCell
{
    public Thickness Border { get; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public int Row { get; }
    public int Column { get; }

    public SudokuCell(int row, int column, Thickness border)
    {
        Row = row;
        Column = column;
        Border = border;
    }

    public SudokuCell(int row, int column, Thickness border, int value)
        : this(row, column, border)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

```
public class SudokuViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<SudokuCell> Cells { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<SudokuCell>();

    public IEnumerable<int> ValidValues { get; } = Enumerable.Range(1, 9);

    private readonly SudokuCell[,] cellsArray;

    private static readonly Random random = new Random();
    public SudokuViewModel()
    {
        cellsArray = new SudokuCell[9, 9];
        for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column < 9; column++)
            {
                if ((row / 3 + column / 3) % 2 == 1)
                    continue;

                double left = 0.5;
                if (column % 3 == 0)
                    left = 3;

                double top = 0.5;
                if (row % 3 == 0)
                    top = 3;

                double right = 0.5;
                if (column % 3 == 2)
                    right = 3;

                double bottom = 0.5;
                if (row % 3 == 2)
                    bottom = 3;

                int value = 0;
                if (random.Next(5) < 2)
                    value = random.Next(9) + 1;

                cellsArray[row, column] = new SudokuCell(
                    row,
                    column,
                    new Thickness(left, top, right, bottom),
                    value);
            }
        }

        foreach (var cell in cellsArray)
        {
            Cells.Add(cell);
        }
    }
}
```

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:SudokuViewModel x:Key="viewModel"/>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="Sudoku.Panel">
            <UniformGrid Columns="9" Rows="9"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Sudoku.CellTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:SudokuCell}">
            <Border BorderBrush="SkyBlue" BorderThickness="{Binding Border}"
                    Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=comboBox}">
                <Border.Style>
                    <Style>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="Border.Opacity" Value="0"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Border.Style>
                <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ValidValues, Source={StaticResource viewModel}}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding Value}"
                          FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          BorderThickness="0"/>
                </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
```

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Cells, Source={StaticResource viewModel}}"
                  ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource Sudoku.CellTemplate}"
                  ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource Sudoku.Panel}"/>
```

[image]